# Webservice consumer behind the proxy?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a webservice consumer in my Lotus Notes application. Consumer works perfectly in testing environment. But customer uses a proxy in their network. I set a proxy values in the Domino server document, but it still doesn't work.

Do I have to use another settings to make my webservice consumer work behind the proxy?

Thanks in advance, JiKra

Comment: Consumer on the Domino server should take the proxy settings from the Domino server. Does the proxy settings work for non-webservices related stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set up the proxy in the Lotus Notes client and not the server since it's the client that consumes the webservice and thereby calls the webservice.

Who provides the web service? The Domino server or a service outside of the network?

Comment: Web service provider is being provided by ZEND framework outside of the network.
The agent, that calls my WS consumer runs scheduled on server. Client is not being involved.